# Make a base64 Quine!

Tags: code-golf, quine

Your challenge is to output a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded version of your source code, and optionally a line break. You must output the correct [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding), if any. [Standard quine rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/58826) apply, shortest answer wins.

It must be a valid [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) encoded base64 string, with no linebreaks (except optionally a trailing newline).

## Test cases:

```
h -> aA==
PPCG! -> UFBDRyE=
Programming Puzzles and Code Golf -> UHJvZ3JhbW1pbmcgUHV6emxlcyBhbmQgQ29kZSBHb2xm
```

#Base64 table

```
0   A   16  Q   32  g   48  w
1   B   17  R   33  h   49  x
2   C   18  S   34  i   50  y
3   D   19  T   35  j   51  z
4   E   20  U   36  k   52  0
5   F   21  V   37  l   53  1
6   G   22  W   38  m   54  2
7   H   23  X   39  n   55  3
8   I   24  Y   40  o   56  4
9   J   25  Z   41  p   57  5
10  K   26  a   42  q   58  6
11  L   27  b   43  r   59  7
12  M   28  c   44  s   60  8
13  N   29  d   45  t   61  9
14  O   30  e   46  u   62  +
15  P   31  f   47  v   63  /
```

If you want to test your submission, try [base64encode.org](https://www.base64encode.org/).

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8595/25180

Comment: RFC 4648 mentiones two alphabets. Which one should we use?

Comment: @Dennis the one in the table.

Comment: WTB a language that outputs the letter of the given index `0->A = win`.

Comment: I've looked at this again after a few months and I still see this as clearly duplicate. All answers to the cryptiographic quine variant challenge work roughly by generating their own source and applying a built-in function to transform it to get its md5sum. Each of those answers could easily be rewritten to use a base64 builtin instead of a md5 built-in, without changing the core technique. I believe that counts as "little modification", making this challenge a duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 27 bytes

```
trap -- 'trap|base64' EXIT
```

Based on this [Bash quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96563/12012). Note the trailing linefeed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6QosUBBV1dBHcSoSUosTjUzUVdwjfAM4fr/HwA)

Comment: why do I obtain dHJhcCAtLSAndHJhcHxiYXNlNjQnIEVYSVQ= and dHJhcCAtLSAndHJhcHxiYXNlNjQnIEVYSVQK ? (last char diff)

Comment: The program needs a trailing linefeed to be a valid base64 quine, which got removed by the syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (ES6), 17 bytes

```js
f=_=>btoa(`f=`+f)
```

I thought this solution would be obvious...

```js
f=_=>btoa(`f=`+f)
console.log(f())
console.log(atob(f()))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>133</s> 112 bytes

```py
from base64 import*;s=b'from base64 import*;s=%r;print(b64encode(s%%s).decode())';print(b64encode(s%s).decode())
```

Base64 representation:

```
ZnJvbSBiYXNlNjQgaW1wb3J0KjtzPWInZnJvbSBiYXNlNjQgaW1wb3J0KjtzPSVyO3ByaW50KGI2NGVuY29kZShzJSVzKS5kZWNvZGUoKSknO3ByaW50KGI2NGVuY29kZShzJXMpLmRlY29kZSgpKQ==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chKbE41cxEITO3IL@oRMu62DZJHbu4apF1QVFmXolGkplJal5yfkqqRrGqarGmXkoqmKOpqY5FAbL8//8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 342 bytes

```c
f(a){putchar(a>61?43+a%2*4:a>51?a-4:a+65+a/26*6);}main(a){char*s="f(a){putchar(a>61?43+a%2*4:a>51?a-4:a+65+a/26*6);}main(a){char*s=%c%s%c,*t=malloc(342);for(sprintf(t,s,34,s,34);*t;f(*t%4*16+*++t/16),f(*t%16*4+*++t/64),f(*t++%64))f(*t/4);}",*t=malloc(342);for(sprintf(t,s,34,s,34);*t;f(*t%4*16+*++t/16),f(*t%16*4+*++t/64),f(*t++%64))f(*t/4);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY1bCoMwEEX3IgSSGUWicT4a1LUMgbSCL0z6VVx76mMJhf4MhwPnjiuezqXkJavP@o7uxZvkjnRvamRRgXlw1@ieiwOQGuSyIiBl94mH@YzOAkKb/bwgnAjC5RDbicdxcbI2lbJ@2WRYt2GOXsY85LW5jrIQrZcQhQFNCIix1KTyS2kCcysyt0IUB6oTy6Pds/@8SekL)

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>72</s> 69 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.*

```
".w6+55*&w.q+!]k;9&wq4-!]kq&[d.t&w;q,ww].4%~4:k;28d3:&wq&[&]?ow4*+k@;
```

Base 64 representation:

```
Ii53Nis1NSomdy5xKyFdazs5JndxNC0hXWtxJltkLnQmdztxLHd3XS40JX40Oms7MjhkMzomd3EmWyZdP293NCora0A7
```

If anything, the base 64 representation looks less inscrutable than the original program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19Jr9xM29RUS61cr1BbMTbb2lKtvNBEF8gqVItO0StRK7cu1Ckvj9UzUa0zscq2NrJIMbYCKlGLVou1zy830dLOdrD@/x8A)

#### Explanation

Since Alice has no base64 built-in, the vast majority of this program is a reduced implementation of base64.  The quine framework prevents me from using `'` to define constants in two bytes, but it also has some advantages.  As luck would have it, the length of the source code is divisible by 3, and the characters `>`, `?`, and `~` do not appear at the end of a 3-character block.

The first step is to create (most of) the base64 alphabet.  The characters `+` and `/` do not appear in the base64 representation of the source code, so we do not need to handle them.  This saves 9 bytes.

```
"      wrap the entire source code in a string and push each byte

.      copy ; from top of stack (i.e., push 59)
w      push return address (i.e., do the following twice)
6+     add 6 to the constant on the stack 
       this gives us 65 in the first iteration, and 71 in the second
55*w   do the following 26 times:
.q+    add tape position to constant
!      store at tape position
]      move tape right
k      return to pushed return address (end both loops)
;      remove constant from the stack, since it's no longer needed
9&w    do 10 times:
q4-    tape position minus 4
!      store at tape position
]      move tape right
k      repeat
q&[    return to position 0
```

Positions 0-61 on the tape are now filled with their base64 character equivalents.  We now convert the source code to base 4.

```
d.     push stack depth (length of code excluding "), and put a useless copy below it
t&w    do that many times:
;      remove top of stack (copy of length on first iteration, 0 otherwise)
q,     move next byte to top of stack (using tape position as a register)
ww     do 4 times:
]      move tape forward (increase counter)
.      duplicate current byte or part thereof
4%     mod 4
~      swap: work with other copy
4:     divide by 4
k      repeat (end both loops)
;28    remove the excess 0 and push the base 4 representation of ",
       except that the first three base 4 digits are already in base 64
```

Finally, we convert from base 4 to base64 and output.

```
d3:&w  push return address once for each output character
q&[    move tape to position 0
&]     move tape to position corresponding to base 64 digit
?      get character from tape
o      output
w4*+   convert next base 64 digit (equivalent to 4*+4*+)
k      repeat until stack is empty
@      terminate
```

Comment: If you can save another byte elsewhere, could you shorten `6a*t` by putting a `;` at the end of the program and a `.` after the `"`?

Comment: As it turns out, rearranging my base 4 -> base 64 conversion allowed me to save a third byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 108 bytes

```
Print[StringDelete[ExportString[StringJoin["Print[", ToString[#0, InputForm], "[]]"], "Base64"], "\n"] & []]
```

Full program. The spaces are necessary as part of the `InputForm` formatting. Output, note the trailing linefeed character:

```
UHJpbnRbU3RyaW5nRGVsZXRlW0V4cG9ydFN0cmluZ1tTdHJpbmdKb2luWyJQcmludFsiLCBUb1N0cmluZ1sjMCwgSW5wdXRGb3JtXSwgIltdXSJdLCAiQmFzZTY0Il0sICJcbiJdICYgW11d
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 202 bytes

```java
v->{String s="v->{String s=%c%s%1$c;return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(s.format(s,34,s).getBytes());}";return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(s.format(s,34,s).getBytes());}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##tVBNa8MwDL3vV4jSgA2tYbTsEtpDocf2srHL6MFz1OLUsYMlB0rJb8@cJZf9gIEEevp44r1ad3odWvR1dR@M00Rw0tY/XwCsZ4xXbRDOIwR452j9DYz4DLaCTpa52@fMQazZGjiDhx0M3Xr/nJdpt/iDClNQ8bo0ZURO0UOd/6vE1qmDJnzbqhvy0ZtQYRRS4W/1EaZzQeoaYqNZ0GqzXZEclw8PRhJSlv3iHziHctLXpm@X9c0yu1F/k20SE8nXRcvZogcxNiokVm2esPDKCJ@ck7Nb/fAD)

- The `String s` contains the unformatted source code.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together.

And then `java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(....getBytes())` is used to encode the entire source code to a Base64-String.

[Try it here with the Base64-encoding part removed to prove it's a quine.](https://tio.run/##dY6xCoMwEIb3PsUhFSJooLSb2DeoS6FL6ZDGWGJjlNwpFPHZ04guHQp3w3//wfc1YhRZ1yvbVG8vjUCEi9B22gFoS8rVQioolwhwJaftCyS7dbqCMcnDdQ4bBkmQllCChQL8mJ2n7RmL6CfFMsb4sJe5UzQ4C8jrzrWCGKbHU4pJPkf/K5@vtH54mkDboONi0wZptlLuD5Fswh8k1fJuIN6HhpjlktnBmGRzn/0X)